# How to save the model output?

Tags: r, stargazer

I have panel data as shown below:

```
emp_id  emp_is_rewarded   month    year    department    salary
222            0            1      1997        IT        70000
.
.
.
222            1            12     2002        IT        90000
333            0            1      1997        HR        40000
.
.
.
333            1            12     2002        HR        55000...
```

I ran the below model:

```
model <- feols(salary ~ emp_is_rewarded | emp_id + month + year + department, df)
```

But when I tried to save the model output using stargazer,

```
stargazer(model, type = "html", out = ".../model.htm")
```

It is showing an error:

```
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

So please let me know what it is regarding.

Comment: I don't see support for this type of model in the stargazer documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the information, is there any alternative apart from stargazer?